# Lost with memory warning when loading images to scroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiimageview

I am getting memory warnings in a `UIScrollView`, where my memory is always 35M on the iPad.
I have a scrollview which has many `UIImageViews`. As I scroll, I am loading images to the scroller, where up to 3 pages are loaded with images (each page has a few images).
I see that when I start scrolling I get a warning. Because the only thing that happens when I scroll is loading images, this must be the problem.

Here is how I load the images. Anything you think is bad practice, please let me know. This method is being called multiple times for each page.

```
  [self downloadImageWithURL:userUrl completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSData *tdata)
     {
         if (succeeded)
         {

             //load back
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^
                            {

                                UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:tdata scale:1];
                                if (image)
                                {
                                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, 0.5);
                                    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

                                    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                                 }


                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                               {


                                                    CostumCell *thisCell= [mainCellsArray objectAtIndex:index];
                                                   UIImageView *view=thisCell.imageView;
                                                   view.clipsToBounds=YES;

                                                   [imagesAreLoading removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:index]];


                                                   //LOAD 
                                                   [UIView transitionWithView:view
                                                                     duration:0.4f
                                                                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                                                   animations:^
                                                    {
                                                         view.image=nil;
                                                        view.image=image;

                                                    }
                                                     completion:nil];



                                               });
                             image=nil;
                            });
```

**EDIT**
I have found that when the GCD is done, if I comment out the line that sets the image to the image view in the animation , I **still** get the memory warnings (images are not even on screen)

Comment: You cache them all at memory, don't you ?

Comment: i stopped caching, caching has no real logic behind it, what it does is to save images for me to next use. but most of the problem with this are occurs right at the beginning, when you first go to get your images, with multiple requests . caching can help much later, when you scroll back .

Comment: I think that is a good time to Profile the app for leaks and allocations.

Answer (score 0):

it is still not entirely there but i found 2 ways that perform much much better and i get warning just rarely .If you have any advice to approve this more, i am glad to hear.
(for example why shouldn't i load here the url asynchrony like before )

first

```
 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
 dispatch_async(queue, ^
    {
        NSDictionary *dic=[mainData objectAtIndex:index];
        NSString *userImageUrl=[dic objectForKey:@"url"];
        NSURL *userUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:userImageUrl];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:userUrl]];
        if (image)
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, 0.8);
            [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        }


 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {

            view.image=image;
            [imagesAreLoading removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:index]];


       });
    });

}
```

And the second which is using NSOperation , do pretty much the same performance :

```
[self.imageOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^
    {
        NSDictionary *dic=[mainData objectAtIndex:index];
        NSString *userImageUrl=[dic objectForKey:@"url"];
        NSURL *userUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:userImageUrl];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:userUrl]];
        if (image)
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, 0.8);
            [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        }



        if (image != nil)
        {


            // now update UI in main queue
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
            {


                view.image=image;


           }];
        }
    }];
```